# Как сделать кнопку отправки формы

Tags: всплывающее-окно, wordpress-плагины

Как сделать на сайте такую кнопку: нажимаешь - всплывающее окно появляется, и там будут формы.

Comment: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms-modal/

Comment: установил данный плагин , но не показывает на админке сайта

Comment: И Ninja Forms поставили https://ninjaforms.com/ ?

Comment: как это делается? можете по подробнее?

Comment: В Ninja Forms надо сделать форму, или взять из примера. Потом через Ninja Forms Modal открывать эту форме во всплывающем окне.